# Xcode 11, how to fix 'Module "FirebaseRemoteConfig" not found'?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, xcode11, firebase-remote-config

After I updated Xcode to version 11, appeared errors "Could not build module 'Firebase'" or "Module 'FirebaseRemoteConfig' not found". Anyone has the same problem with Xcode 11? How to fix this?

I tried to update cocoapods, gem and firebase pod. 
Also I tried deintegrate and install pods again, removed DerivedData and reset Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Try building to update the ModuleCache.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien doesn't help